# Wrong line spacing when changing font size for caption of algorithm

Tags: captions, line-spacing, algorithm2e

I am using the `algorithm2e` package and want to change the font size for captions of figures as well as for captions of algorithms. The problem is that I get different line spacings for the two approaches (too much spacing in the captions for algorithms). The goal is that both captions look the same. Below a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\SetAlCapNameFnt{\footnotesize}
\SetAlCapFnt{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem.}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick assessment shows the redefinition of captions from [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and the capability to set its of formats may have conflicting outcomes when switching fonts. Inserting `\endgraf` at the end of the caption restores the line-spacing associated with the prevailing font. This is achieved via a patch using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Before the patch:

[image]

After the patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,caption,algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,caption,algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\algocf@latexcaption}{#3}{#3\endgraf}{}{}
\makeatother
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\SetAlCapNameFnt{\footnotesize}
\SetAlCapFnt{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem.}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem. 
  Some very very long caption that illustrates the problem.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```